# Operator '&' is not defined for string "INSERT INTO

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am trying to insert "NameofProduct" into my database and I am getting an error Operator '&' is not defined for string "INSERT INTO

The insert statement only fails when the line below is used to populate "NameofProduct" Can anyone find anything wrong with this?

```
NameofProduct = Session("Product1").ToString &
                "," &
                Session("Product2").ToString.Replace("Select....", "") & 
                "," &
                Session("Product3").ToString &
                "," &
                Session("Product4").ToString &
                "," &
                Session("ProductManual").ToString
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that 1) your not using a procedure to insert these values that uses parameters (which allows for SQL injection) and 2) that one of the values being input has a "&" in it.  Consider: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: what do you try to fill into NameOfProduct string ?

Comment: just like toothpaste, toothbrush,,,, etc

Comment: Do any values attempting to be inserted contain the character & or : or | or ' or "?  Anyone one of these may throw off results w/o proper handling or use of parameter query. mentioned by fatcat1111

Comment: Not that I know of, I just tried the following product (the value of NameofProduct) and it failed with same error  "Astrobrush Refill Point 6,,Select....,Select....,"

Comment: Please show the whole code where you are using this NameOfProduct variable.

Comment: What is the offending *value* of that `NameofProduct`?

Comment: I got it working,. I was using .selecteditem instead of .text when assigning it to my session variables. Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like you may need line continuation characters for parts of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that all of the Session members (e.g., Session("ProductManual")) have values at all times?

In any case, you're better off going with a parameterized query, rather than building the query string this way. This will be less error prone, protect you from SQL injections, and is faster (as the query won't need to be prepared each time). [Check out this page on MSDN](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb).

Comment: They will not have values at all times, is this why?

Comment: @user1342164 so long the column into which you are inserting can accept NULL values that should not be a problem

Comment: @user1342164 If they don't, they're going to be joined in such a way that there will be trailing commas. Also, you need to verify that you don't have "&" symbols in those values. Really though I wouldn't recommend changing the code to verify the data; the right thing to do here is to parameterize your query.

Comment: Ya, I am required that this field have in the column all products separated by a comma toothpaste, toothbrush, etc.

Comment: For the parameter qry are you saying this is something that needs to be on the SQL end of things?

Comment: @user1342164 no, you don't need to modify the server, though if you want to go a step further and create a stored procedure that would require a small DB change. Relevant XKCD: http://xkcd.com/327/